# Converting 12 hour to 24 hour time format in sqlite

Tags: datetime, sqlite, format

Say I have a script named 'importscript.sql' to create a table and populate it from a text file named 'rawdata.txt' like so:

```
    CREATE TABLE rawdata (
    timestamp text,
    value REAL
    );
    .separator ,
    .import '~/path of the file/rawdata.txt' rawdata
```

The 'rawdata.txt' file looks like this:

```
4/14/2012 3:50:09 PM,24.7
4/14/2012 3:51:09 PM,24.2
4/14/2012 3:52:09 PM,99.3
```

Then creating a database named RAWDATA.db with the rawdata table in it in the command prompt using:

```
sqlite3 RAWDATA.db < ~/path to the script/importscript.sql
```

The table when the import is complete will look like this:

```
timestamp              value    
4/14/2012 3:50:09 PM   24.7
4/14/2012 3:51:09 PM   24.2
4/14/2012 3:52:09 PM   99.3
```

But I want it to look like this

```
timestamp              value
4/14/2012 15:50:09      24.7
4/14/2012 15:51:09      24.2
4/14/2012 15:52:09      99.3
```

How do I convert this timestamp column into a 24 hour format?

Comment: Strong recommendation: Store dates in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have modified the question and really showed what I have done.

Comment: @LS_dev: In database, I'm storing date time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format but I want to read it back with am/pm format. i.e.: input: `2012-04-14 15:50:09` and desired output: `2012-04-14 03:50:09 PM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make use of SQLite date/time functions and allow date comparisons (and sorting), date should be stored in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM-SS`.

So, my answer will address your question and this date conversion:

```
UPDATE rawdata SET timestamp=(SELECT DATETIME(SUBSTR(timestamp, s2+1, 4)||'-01-01',
  SUBSTR(timestamp,    1, s1   -1)||' months', '-1 months',
  SUBSTR(timestamp, s1+1, s2-s1-1)||' days', '-1 days',
  SUBSTR(timestamp, s3+1, s4-s3-1)||' hours',
  SUBSTR(timestamp, s4+1, s5-s4-1)||' minutes',
  SUBSTR(timestamp, s5+1, s6-s5-1)||' seconds',
  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(timestamp, s3+1, s4-s3-1) = '12' THEN '-12 hours' ELSE '0 hours' END,
  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(timestamp, s6+1) LIKE 'PM' THEN '+12 hours' ELSE '0 hours' END
)
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    INSTR(SUBSTR(timestamp, s1+1), '/')+s1 AS s2,
    INSTR(SUBSTR(timestamp, s4+1), ':')+s4 AS s5,
    INSTR(SUBSTR(timestamp, s3+1), ' ')+s3 AS s6
  FROM (
    SELECT timestamp,
      INSTR(timestamp, '/') AS s1, 
      INSTR(timestamp, ' ') AS s3, 
      INSTR(timestamp, ':') AS s4
  )
));
```

This horrible block get all separators position, reconstruct date from components and handle `PM`. Note that `1...11AM => +0` and  `1...11PM => +12`, but `12AM => -12` and `12PM => +0`!

Check it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3c09f/9).