# DateTime in SQLite has AM/PM

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I have a database that is filled with log data by an external program.

One column is a timestamp of type DateTime.

Depending on the external programs host settings of time format, it either writes into the database using 24h or 12h format with AM/PM.

This query I used to get the time (on the same machine, but two database files from different external devices):

```
SELECT Time FROM tabData
```

The output (from a machine with AM/PM time setting)

```
2017-05-31 8:52:26 AM
```

and another (from a machine with 24h time setting)

```
2017-05-31 08:52:26
```

Why does the database datetime keep that 12h mode with AM/PM? Can I somehow change the format of the database datetime by SQL?

I further want to read these data into a DataTable in C#, and I'd prefer a SQL statement to read any given datetime as 24 hour datetime.

Comment: Have you tried storing datetime stamp in ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`)? Are you wanted to convert into 24-hour format like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655003/converting-12-hour-to-24-hour-time-format-in-sqlite?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I can't control how the external program writes the data into the database.

Comment: So, are you mean that the conversion job should be handled by SQLite query itself? If that's what you want, first I advise you that datetime conversion by query should be avoided, since SQL is a tiered architecture the display format handler should be done in presentation layer.

Comment: SQLite has no [DateTime](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) type. I can assume that your DB data is stored in a string as the TEXT type. Use appropriate [functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for working with date and time.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov according to the tables schema, it's a `datetime`. Might that be actually only a string?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for your ideas, I found i could in fact change how the external program writes into the database, it now inserts as ISO format. I'll leave this question open though, this is not the solution to my question here.

Answer (score 0):

If SQLite is anything like MSSQL and Oracle, it doesn't have a **Format** for datetime except for its internal storage format that you shouldn't need to know anything about. The format you see only shows up when you use a **Client** to query that date, and then the actual format depends on the client you use, for instance general time settings chosen on the client machine.

Comment: The database was written by a machine with 12h time setting, and i read the database on a different machine with 24h time setting, yet it showed as 12h with AM/PM...